# Where are the parlour games on topic?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

On which site (or maybe proposal) are the parlour games on topic?

I mean both the sit-up games like Mafia or Guess-The-Rule, and the terrain ones, like Assasin?

Answer (score 1):

We have a [Board & Card Games](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange.

We also have a [Role Playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange.

Do read their help center documentation about what is and is not on-topic before posting.

However, it sounds like your topic doesn't quite fit either.

Comment: I've found there only that: http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/230/social-games-allowed/232#232 and it would suggest that games based on the position and movement of players would not be allowed, so it's not so clear they are all on topic there.

Comment: @alfresco02 - there is also an [rpg.se] site.

Comment: You suggest, I should copy that question to all possible site's metas?

Comment: @alfresco02 - what would that achieve over and above what you posted here?

Comment: It would solicit input directly from the communities in question about what questions they want to field. Asking here instead doesn't make a lot of sense to me. My impression of the meta-question on Board Games is not that it rules out questions like this, and no one objected to the question being asked. Surely Role-Playing Games could benefit similarly from considering the meta-question independently.